# How to guarantee two related models get saved?

Tags: python, django, django-models

How do I guarantee data only gets saved when the related objects are both filled with data?

```
class A(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()

class B(A):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.URLField()
```

I insert data by accessing model B:

```
b = B()
b.title = 'title'
b.slug = 'slug'
b.author = 'author'
b.url = 'www.google.com'
b.save()
```

If an error occurs in model B then model A still gets saved.
How can I prevent model A from saving when model B doesn't get saved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your environment, [transactions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/transactions/#topics-db-transactions) are probably the answer

Answer (score 2):

Database transactions?

Answer (score 0):

Override B's save method ([as described in the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods)), have it call A's [full_clean](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) method. if it raises an exception, just don't save the model.

Comment: Well that's not the problem.
If B raises an exception A still gets saved.